# How to Install the magento manually without wamp or xampp?

Tags: php, database, magento2.2.3

How to Install the magento 2.2.3 manually without using wamp or xampp?

I had installed apache and mysql on my system.

Comment: Do you have linux or windows?

Comment: windows 10 @AdrianZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you install xampp / wamp on windows that will be easiest way to setup php projects however if you still want to do all stuff manually then visit the below url and read step by step guide how to install and configure your local server ( windows ) :

https://docs.moodle.org/34/en/Manual_install_on_Windows_7_with_Apache_and_MySQL

Comment: Thank for Replying.. I had checked your link. it guides for moodle installation. :(  @Naveed

Comment: it guides for moodle, but you can follow the guide to just setup apache,php and mysql and how to configure it. then you can simply install magento or anyother php project.